# Can I define the target table for int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter based on the received message?

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-integration

I´m using Spring Integration JDBC support to persist a message in one of several tables (>20) depending on a certain condition (stored in the message headers as "table"):

```
<int:channel id="cmTablesJdbcChannel"></int:channel>
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="cmTablesJdbcChannel"
    id="cmTableJdbcOutputAdaptor" data-source="datasource"
    query="insert into TABLE_NAME values (int_id, parent_int_id, name) values (:headers[int_id],:headers[parent_int_id],:headers[name])">
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I have tried to replace TABLE_NAME by several expressions but none worked:

```
${headers['table']}
#{headers['table']}
:[headers['table]}
```

I´m trying to avoid the usage of 20 different outbound channel adaptors and reuse a single one but dynamically setting the name of the table to be used. Do you know if it is possible?

There were similar questions but related to the parameters to be used: [How can I create a dynamic query for Spring Integration JDBC outbound-channel-adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005450/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-query-for-spring-integration-jdbc-outbound-channel-ad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't work now and `TABLE_NAME` can't be as a parameter.

Feel free to raise [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) issue to consider something like `query-expression` to build the `INSERT/UPDATE` SQL at runtime against request message.

In meantime you should use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` from the some custom POJO to be used from the `<outbound-channel-adapter>` or like a complex expression:

```
<service-activator input-channel="cmTablesJdbcChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" 
    expression="@jdbcTemplate.update('insert into ' + headers.table + ' (int_id, parent_int_id, name) values (:int_id,:parent_int_id,:name)', headers)"/>
```

Note, don't use direct SQL expression building with the parameter values. The `parametrized` variant with `:` is preferable way for any RDBMS. It will be compiled on the server side (indexes, query plan etc.) and reused for all other upcoming executions.

Comment: That´s a neat way to do it! I was afraid I had to do all the implementation in a ServiceActivator class... I´m gonna give it a try. Thanks!